# Spring Boot renaming server.port in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, properties, ip

I have a spring boot server app in my src/test folder that is configured to run with my test.properties.

Currently my properties looks like this:

```
server.port=9119
server.ssl.enabled=false
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
logging.file=messages
logging.file.max-size=50MB
logging.level.com.nulogix=DEBUG
billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
billing.engine.port=9119
billing.engine.api.version=0.97
billing.engine.core.version=0.97
billing.engine.core.name=Patient_Responsibility
```

I want to retire server.port and point my server to get the port from billing.engine.port.

Is it possible to configure Spring to do this?

My spring app main class currently looks like this

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MockServerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MockServerApp.class)       
        .properties("spring.config.name:test")
        .build()
        .run(args);


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try server.port=${billing.engine.port} ?

Comment: that works but I was wondering if there's a way to completey remove server.port. So I just have billing.engine.port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code

```
@Component
public class ServerPortCustomizer 
  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> {
    @Value("${billing.engine.port}")
    private String SERVERPORTNO;
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.setPort(SERVERPORTNO);
    }
}
```

and also change your application.properties

```
#server.port=9119
billing.engine.port=9119
```

it's not a tested code.... I am writing this code based on my knowledge

Comment: This worked for me except SERVERPORTNO is an integer, not String